# Does Pusher allow a transport payload in non-ASCII (JSON) format?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, protocol-buffers, pusher

I'm currently sending messages to Pusher in .NET like this:

```
var result = pusher.Trigger( "channel-1", "test_event", new { message = "hello world" } );
```

and receiving them in JavaScript like this:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('APP_KEY');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('channel-1');
channel.bind('test_event', function(data) {
        // process
    }
);
```

Would it be possible to send the payload in a different (smaller) format, for example like Protocol Buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send binary data because the data you send is used as a string field in a JSON object, or a query string parameter,  when it is `POST`ed to Pusher. This is described in the [HTTP API reference](https://pusher.com/docs/rest_api#events).

What you could do is encode it to binary with protobuf, and then encode the resulting binary as a string with a base64 encoder.

The problem you will have is with .NET library. This takes the data you want to send as an `object`, and encodes it as JSON internally. You would have to post to the HTTP API directly, or modify the .NET library to expose a trigger method that takes a `string` instead of an `object`.